# Hide sort indicator/arrow in table column header

Tags: java, javafx-2, graphic

Is there any way to remove sort indicator/arrow from sorted tablecolumn in javafx 2.2 table columns ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can be done via css with

```
.table-view .arrow {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-shape: " ";
}
```

Comment: Also works in JavaFx 8. Thank's a lot. But how have you be aware of this ?!

Comment: Hi. This doesn't work for me (and apparently I don't add any style class "arrow") . Can you please update the answer with more directions? Thanks.

Comment: This removes the arrow but does not remove the multi-column sort order dots.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.no-sort-icon .column-header,
.no-sort-icon .column-header .arrow {
    -fx-background-image: null;
}
```

Then you add "no-sort-icon" to the tableView's style classes.